# What is :cascade in rails schema.rb and where did it come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After adding another migration and occasional decision to drop and migrate I checked my schema.rb
and saw this

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
```

I haven't committed this changes yet and on remote I have this

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
```

Now I have cascade in front of each table. What is cascade and where did it come from?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[The docs explain what `:cascade` does](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table):

> `:force` - Set to `:cascade` to drop dependent objects as well. Defaults to `false`.

One reason you may be seeing this is a change in Rails 4.2 in `SchemaDumper` to use `:cascade`, [release notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes).

Release notes about change:

> `SchemaDumper` uses `force: :cascade` on `create_table`. This makes it possible to reload a schema when foreign keys are in place.

Answer (score 7):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table

:force
Set to `true` to drop the table before creating it. Set to `:cascade` to drop dependent objects as well. Defaults to `false`.